# This audio format (AC3) not supported in MX player

Tags: audio, mx-player

I am trying to play one video in `hindi` language in **MX player**. but it shows `This audio format (AC3) is not supported`.

Error shows in below picture:

[image]

Does anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: AFAIK because of licensing issues, MX Player dropped AC3 support. There is/was a plugin you could download, but I don't know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/mx-player/mx-player-custom-codec-dts-support-t2156254) is what you need.
Download the codec, place it in your internal storage, then Settings > decoder > Custom codec. This should fix your problem.